# Creating a subgraph of a graph in TensorFlow given a condition

Tags: python, tensorflow

In `tf.slim` or the standard `TensorFlow`; can we save a subgraph of a graph given a condition? Say, we would like to generate (or save as a new graph) from all non-zero elements within each layer? Say `conv1` has this weight array:

```
conv2 = [ 1 0 2 0 0 3 4]
```

These weights are interconnected with the preceding and the succeeding layer. Can I downsize the layer to:

```
conv2_new = [ 1 2 3 4]
```

As if I dropped the connections and the weights of certain elements in each layer and the executing flow adapts itself given the new dimension of the layer? Any suggestions/code would be appreciated.